# I want to highlight single column in google sheet that will find duplicate values by matching 3 columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting, countif

[image]I want to highlight "C" column in google sheet that will find duplicate values. "C" & "D" column matches values and it is marking cell as red, but I can't figure out the formula how to match "B" & "C" column and turn those values in green. Currently I'm using this formula =COUNTIF(C:D, C1)=2

I want all "B" values green in "C" column & all "D" values red in "C" column at the same time in google sheet through conditional formatting. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Are you using Excel? Or Googlesheets? There is a BIG difference, so we need to know.

Comment: I am using Googlesheets

Comment: Then you should not tag Excel. Only use the tags that are relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following.

For C to go red when there's a match in D

```
=COUNTIF(D:D,C1)>0
```

For C to go green when there's a match in B

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,C1)>0
```

*APPLY TO RANGE*: `C:C`

-

[image]